# Stop background from stretching while using overscan on Android 10

Tags: adb

I have a broken touchscreen zone that i want to disable. So i used Overscan to shift my screen on the right by 10px. However in Apps such as Youtube the main content is shown on the correct size however the background stretches to the whole screen so a distracting bar of content is shown on that 10px.

Comment: The touch screen is on its last legs.  You are just delaying the inevitable by a few months.  Why not replace the screen and/or the phone.

Comment: I don't have the money right now. Just a few months more time would be really helpful.